# IntegrityError in Django testcase

Tags: django, python-3.x, testing, django-models, multiple-databases

I am suspecting that `transaction.atomic()` does not commit my `instance` to the database during testing. The problem might comes from multiple databases

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel


class PIIField(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Personal Information Identifier configuration model
    This model is M2M on `Plan`
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Plan(timestamp.Model, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "catalog_plans"

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="plans")
    coverages = models.ManyToManyField(Coverage, through="PlanCoverage")
    code = models.TextField(null=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    pii_fields = models.ManyToManyField(PIIField, related_name='plans', related_query_name='plan')
```

Here is my `tests.py`

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from model_mommy import mommy
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

from catalog.models import Plan
from pii_fields.models import PIIField


class PIIFieldTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    databases = {'default', 'product', 'customer'}

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.plan = mommy.make(Plan, code='88', name='Non risky life') # single `plan` with no` pii_fields` attached
            self.field_1 = mommy.make(PIIField, name='first_name', detail='text box', order=1)
            self.field_2 = mommy.make(PIIField, name='last_name', detail='text box', order=2)
            self.field_3 = mommy.make(PIIField, name='weight', detail='real number', order=3)
            self.field_4 = mommy.make(PIIField, name='nationality', detail='drop down', order=4)
            self.plan.pii_fields.set([self.field_1, self.field_2, self.field_3, self.field_4])

    def test_get(self):
        """
        Get the endpoint and see the payload sample
        :return:
        """
        client = APIClient()
        url = reverse('api:pii_field-detail', args=[self.plan.id])
        res = client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_200_OK, res.status_code)
```

Error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "catalog_plans_pii_fields" violates foreign key constraint "catalog_plans_pii_fi_piifield_id_58130345_fk_pii_field"
DETAIL:  Key (piifield_id)=(1) is not present in table "pii_fields_piifield".
```

**Question:**
How to test my database and viewsets?

Comment: Why are you using transaction.atomic here at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because I suspect the `IntegrityError` raises from uncommitted transaction while test is being run

Answer (score 0):

I have to use another syntax to add my records. I had tried `bulk_create`, but it does not work

```
self.plan.pii_fields.create(name='first_name', detail='text box', order=1)
self.plan.pii_fields.create(name='last_name', detail='text box', order=2)
self.plan.pii_fields.create(name='weight', detail='real number', order=3)
self.plan.pii_fields.create(name='nationality', detail='drop down', order=4)
```